# R: how to fill boxplot grouped by sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to fill boxplot grouped by sequence of values. Each box should be filled by different color from color palettes. How can I do this?

````
```data <- data.frame(tavg=sample(-30:30,2000,replace=TRUE),attendance=sample(100:30000,1000,replace=TRUE)))```
````

````
box <- data %>% 
  ggplot( aes(cut(tavg, seq(-20,+30,5)), y=attendance, fill=tavg)) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.1) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(
      legend.position="none",
      plot.title = element_text(size=11)
    ) +
    ggtitle("Title") +
    labs(x = "Temperature") ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
library(ggplot2)

#  data
set.seed(123)  
data <- data.frame(tavg = sample(-30:30, 2000, replace = TRUE),
                   attendance = sample(100:30000, 1000, replace = TRUE))


my_colors <- viridisLite::viridis(length(unique(cut(data$tavg, seq(-20, 30, 5)))))


ggplot(data, aes(x = cut(tavg, seq(-20, 30, 5)), 
                 y = attendance, 
                 fill = factor(cut(tavg, seq(-20, 30, 5)), 
                 levels = unique(cut(tavg, seq(-20, 30, 5))))))+
         geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
         geom_jitter(color = "black", size = 0.4, alpha = 0.1) +
         scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
         labs(x = "Temperature", y = "Attendance", fill="Sequence") +
         ggtitle("Title") +
         theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How to assign colors depending on temperature? I mean sort - cooler colors for cooler temp. Now it sorts differently